# Hive: What Happens if I Manually Copy Data Files into Location Folder of a Table?

Tags: hive, hdfs, load

I have tried copying data files into the location folder of a table (rather than using the load command), and it works in the sense that I can query the new data.  However, all sources that I see will always use load command to do this; they never talk about copying data files directly to the location folder.  I get the impression that copying files directly to location folder is not a good idea, but I can't see any explanation as to why it is a bad idea.

Does anyone know why data files should not be copied directly to the location folder of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hive prior version 3.0 Load operations are pure copy/move operations that move datafiles into locations corresponding to Hive tables/partitions.

Additional load operations are supported by Hive 3.0 onwards as Hive internally rewrites the load into an INSERT AS SELECT. In Hive 3.0 onwards LOAD command takes care about partitions and buckets as well.

See documentation for more details: [Loading Files into tables](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Loadingfilesintotables).

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this would depend on whether the table is a Hive Managed Table vs. and External Table.

Generally External Tables aren't bucketed or partitioned i.e. they're managed by some external process. In that case it should be perfectly fine to place the files there as long as you have a mechanism for data control.

Hive Managed Tables are a different story though. Hive manages partitions by splitting the files into folders (and subfolders). Buckets are managed by hashing the keys into different files. In these cases you'll likely get unpredictable results or errors if you place files on your own into these folders.

This gets even more complicated in the case of transaction tables which require compaction (and until Hive 2.0 required bucketing)

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the data directly to the table location and it will be reflected to the queries. But if the table is a partitioned table and if the files contains data for more than one partition then just copying the files won't help you, you have to load the data using load command in this case.

If your file contains data for a single partition you can copy that file to that particular partition and do msck repair for the table, this will update the metadata of table and results will reflect to your query.

Comment: Thanks; any idea why no one talks about this method of adding data files to a table?  Seems like the simplest thing to do, at least for Hive newbies.  But I haven't found a single source which talked about this.

Comment: In most of the production cases we have external tables with partition and bucketing so simply copying files will not work in that use case, However for exploring the concept and/or for tables without partition we can go with copying files directly to the location.